# Include / exclude tests by fully qualified package name

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to specify a set of tests by fully qualified package name, using Maven 3.6.3 with maven-surefire-plugin 3.0.0-M5 on OpenJDK 11. The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html#Fully_qualified_class_name) states...

> As of Surefire Plugin 2.19.1, the syntax with fully qualified class
> names or packages can be used

...and goes on to give an example:

```
<include>my.package.*, another.package.*</include>
```

If I have my test class `Test1.java` in a package called `some.test.pkg1` and use:

```
<include>some.test.pkg1.*</include>
```

or even:

```
<include>some.test.*</include>
```

...the test won't be executed. Why is that?

---

**Update 1:** To provide all the infos requested by @khmarbaise, I've pushed a small project to github, please see here: https://github.com/zb226/so69604251-maven-surefire-plugin

---

**Update 2:** @ori-dar suggested dropping the asterisk `*` (or `.*`), but it does not help.

---

**Update 3:** I found mentions that by default Maven expects to have Test classes' names ending with `Test`, so I tried to rename the test to `MavenTest.java`, which didn't help either.

---

**Update 4:** For posterity, [SUREFIRE-1789](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1789) seems to deal with this exact issue.
[SUREFIRE-1389](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1389) is related. [SUREFIRE-1191](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1191) introduced the [corresponding section in the docs](https://github.com/sverhagen/maven-surefire/commit/544591c9d18966f514bb4273aa06deed186a6810).

---

**Update 5:** I added small test runners for Windows/*nix to my repo linked above, to check which versions are affected by this behaviour. Turns out it's any and all but 2.19.1 - which means that the official documentation is misleading if not to say wrong for over 5 years now `:(`

Comment: Please show full pom file ... log file output ...and the test case which is not executed ...which JDK version is being used?

Comment: @khmarbaise: Updated the question, please have a look at the repo - thanks!

Comment: Same result if you run without asterisk?  `<include>some.test.pkg1</include>` as opposed to `<include>some.test.pkg1.*</include>`. The later may scan for tests in sub packages.

Comment: @OriDar Same result without asterisk. If you want to check more closely, please clone the provided repo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, this looks like a bug in maven-surefire-plugin, or at best some behavior change that isn't documented properly.

I took the sample you posted to GitHub, downgraded it to maven-surefire-plugin 2.19.1, and it works just fine.

You may want to report this bug [Apache's Jira](https://issues.apache.org/).

Comment: You are right, it's stops working from version 2.20 on. I hadn't stepped down the versions so far...